# Modify the same data structure when called from another method

Tags: java

Lets say I have 2 classes:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Class B cB = new ClassB();
           cB.modifyMethod(parameter);    
    }
}

class B {
    private ArrayList<String> dataStucture = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void modifyMethod(int parameter) {
        //...............
    }
}
```

What I intend to do is to modify `dataStructure` 3 times. Each time based on a new parameter and called form `classA`. So if I call one time `modifyMethod` it will create the list I want, but when I call it secondly I want it to work on the same list, not to create a new one.

can you help me fix this?

Comment: that's not how you instantiate a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what you want then you can make dataStructure static

```
 private static ArrayList<String> dataStucture = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It will be shared among all instances of B.

Answer (score 0):

`Class B` is only instantiated once in `Class A`, so all modifications to the ArrayList `datastructure` will be for that particular instance of `datastructure` as well.

Do something like this:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            B cB = new B();
           cB.modifyMethod(parameter);    
    }
}

class B {
    private ArrayList<String> dataStucture = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void modifyMethod(String parameter) {
        dataStructure.add(parameter);
    }
}
```

I changed the type of parameter in `modifyMethod` to `String` since the ArrayList `dataStucture` is String. I also changed the way you instantiated your class B, you don't need to keyword Class in front of B to make instantiate it.